# missing Content-Type error while uploading a file using busboy

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm trying to upload a file to s3 in next.js using Busboy but I'm getting the missing Content-Type error even though I defined them in fetch.

**here is the upload api :**

```
export const POST = async (req, res) => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.S3_BUCKET_REGION,
  });
  
  const busboy = Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
  busboy.on("file", async (fieldName, file, filename, encoding, mimtype) => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: filename,
      Body: file,
    };

    const uplaod = s3.upload(params).promise();
    console.log("upload:", uplaod);
    res.json({ message: "File uploaded successfully" });
  });
  return req.pipe(busboy);
};
```

**and here is the fetch :**

```
const handleUpload = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/api/upload", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });
      if (res.ok) {
        router.push("/projects");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

I tried to deleted the headers but I still got the same error.